# If polynomials agree on roots, then they have the same irreducible factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $K$ is a field and $f_1,f_2 \in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ are polynomials such that $f_1(a)=0 \iff f_2(a)=0$ for any element $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n) \in \tilde{K}^n$, the algebraic closure of $K^n$. I would like to show that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have the same irreducible factors in $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. I am not really sure where to begin. I know that a variety is irreducible if its ideal is prime and any variety has
a unique decomposition as a finite union of irreducible subvarieties. Any reference or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Well, $K^n$ is not a field, so it doesn’t have an algebraic closure; presumably you mean the $n$th power of the algebraic closure of $K$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, sorry.

Comment: Do you know the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: Yes, I do know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nullstellensatz precisely says that $f_1$ and $f_2$ have the same zero locus if and only if the ideals $(f_1)$ and $(f_2)$ have the same radical. You can easily see however (using unique factorization in $K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$) that the radical of $(f)$ is the ideal generated by the product of the distinct irreducible factors of $(f)$. Hence $f_1$ and $f_2$ must have the same irreducible factors.

Comment: So we have
$$V(f_1)=V(f_2),$$
so
$$I(V(f_1))=I(V(f_2)),$$
and by the Nullstellensatz
$$\sqrt{(f_1)}=\sqrt{(f_2)}.$$
Then since $\sqrt{(f_1)}\subseteq \sqrt{(f_2)}$, $f_2 \mid f_1^k$ for some $k$.
Similarly $f_1 \mid f_2^l$ for some $l$.
How can I conclude they have the same irreducible factors?

Comment: Suppose $f_1$ has an irreducible factor that $f_2$ hasn't. Then $f_1$ can't divide $f_2^l$.